# Como separar cadena en sus diferentes etiquetas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estimados espero se encuentren bien, tengo el siguiente inconveniente y no logro dar con el resultado, tengo el siguiente párrafo el cual quiero separar palabra por palabra, respetando las etiquetas internas, es decir que si existe dentro del párrafo una etiqueta **strong**, la considere como una sola palabra.

**Párrafo de ejemplo**

```
<p id="maquina">Este es un <strong>texto con negrita</strong> de prueba</p>
```

**Código Utilizado**

```
var texto = $('#maquina');
var palabras = texto.split(' ');
console.log(palabras);
```

Pero obtengo lo siguiente

```
[
"Este", 
"es",
"un",
"<strong>texto",
"con",
"negrita</strong>",
"de",
"prueba"
]
```

Y me gustaría que fuese de la siguiente forma

```
 [
    "Este", 
    "es",
    "un",
    "<strong>texto con negrita</strong>",
    "de",
    "prueba"
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías resolverlo usando:

- [Node.childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)

  > La propiedad de solo lectura Node.childNodes  devuelve una colección de hijos nodes del elemento dado donde el primer nodo hijo es asignado un índice 0.
- [element.nodeName](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName)

  > Devuelve el nombre del nodo actual, en forma de cadena.
- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

  > La propiedad textContent de la interfaz Node representa el contenido de texto de un nodo y sus dencendientes.
- [Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

  > El atributo outerHTML del interfaz DOM element obtiene el fragmento HTML serializado que describe el elemento incluyendo sus descendientes. [...]

Entonces, usando `childNodes` obtenemos todos los nodos hijos del elemento `maquina`.
Recorremos cada uno de los elementos y verificamos el `nodeName` de cada uno, en el caso de ser igual a `#text` separamos la cadena contenida en espacios.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let element = document.getElementById('maquina'),
  words = [];

// Recorremos los nodos hijos
element.childNodes.forEach(element => {
  // Si es un nodo tipo texto
  if (element.nodeName === '#text') {
    // Separamos la cadena por espacios y agregamos las palabras al arreglo
    words.push.apply(words, element.textContent.trim().split(' '));
  } else {
    words.push(element.outerHTML);
  }
});
console.log(words);
```

```html
<p id="maquina">Este es un <strong>texto con negrita</strong> de prueba</p>
```

Comment: Me a servido mucho la respuesta, ahora una consulta, como seria si el texto en vez de estar en un parrafo, se encuentra en una variable ?, ejemplo var parrafo = 'Este es un <strong>texto con negrita</strong> de prueba', si recorro dicha variable me da error en el foreach, como puedo adaptar eso ?

Comment: @JonathanAlarcon, si tenes una nueva pregunta, te invito [a crearla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!